# changing value on a <select> when using CreateContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

hello guys im trying to bluid select using CreateContext function and after one or 2 time the app sent error, its mean it work just one or 2 time then stop the sent error

this is the Data

```
const FristSelectData = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(FristSelectContext);
  console.log('state',state);

  return (
    <>
      <TableCell align="center"> 
          <FormControl style={ {margin: 1 ,minWidth: 120} }>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-native-select">Fristbegin</InputLabel>
                <Select native defaultValue="" 
                        id="grouped-select"
                        // open={state.select}
                        // onClose={() => setState(state => ({ ...state, select: false }))}
                        // onOpen={() => setState(state => ({ ...state, select: true }))}
                        value={state.frist}
                        onChange={(e) => 
                          {console.log('e',e.target)
                          setState( state => ({ ...state, frist: e.target.value})
                          )}}
                        >
                        <option value={1}>Sofort</option>
                        <option value={2}>Zum Jaresende</option>
                </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </TableCell>
    </>
  )
}


export default FristSelectData
```

and this is the Context componets

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


const FristSelectContext = React.createContext([{}, () => {}]);

const FristSelectProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ frist: ''});
  
  return (
    <FristSelectContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {props.children}
    </FristSelectContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { FristSelectContext, FristSelectProvider };
```

this is the error, its make no sense the value is 1 or 2

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
(anonymous function)
C:/git/frontend/EDIB_CMS/OrchardCMS/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Begis.AkteV2/begis.akte.v2/src/components/Settings/ManagementSettings/DeletionPeriodConfig/FristSelectData.js:28
  25 | value={state.frist}
  26 | onChange={(e) => 
  27 |   {console.log('e',e.target)
> 28 |   setState( state => ({ ...state, frist: e.target.value})
     | ^  29 |   )}}
  30 | >
  31 | <option value={1}>Sofort</option>
View compiled
▶ 5 stack frames were collapsed.
FristSelectProvider
C:/git/frontend/EDIB_CMS/OrchardCMS/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Begis.AkteV2/begis.akte.v2/src/components/Settings/ManagementSettings/DeletionPeriodConfig/FristSelectContext.js:6
  3 | 
  4 | const FristSelectContext = React.createContext([{}, () => {}]);
  5 | 
> 6 | const FristSelectProvider = (props) => {
  7 |   const [state, setState] = useState({ frist: ''});
  8 |   
  9 |   return (
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get value from select -- REACT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850489/get-value-from-select-react)

Answer (score 0):

i just fix the problem, i have to save the value in const
like this and it will work

```
onChange={(e) => {
                            console.log('e', e.target);
                            const stuff = e.target.value;
                            setState((state) => ({...state, frist: stuff}));
                        }}
```